# Hide html table column using header class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]
I am dynamically generating table using Javascript and php response. I have assigned different class to different header of html table. Now I want to hide specifc column using its header class without adding any class into rows.

How I am generating my html table is given below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < tableHeaderData.length; i++){
    html += "<td class='th task_'" + tableHeaderData[i] + ">" + tableHeaderData[i] +"</td>";
}

var totalDays = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < projectAndTask.length; i++){
    totalDays += projectAndTask[i].days/2
    html += "<tr>"+
        "<td>" + (i+1) +"</td>"+//serial no.
        "<td>" + projectAndTask[i].empName + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + (projectAndTask[i].days/2) + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + projectAndTask[i].category + "</td>";

    var loopLastIndex = 4; // this variable will save the last position of k -loop in order to run it from the same last position

       for(var j = 0; j < projectAndTask[i].taskArray.length; j++){
        for(var k = loopLastIndex; k < tableHeaderData.length; k++) {
            if (tableHeaderData[k].split('_')[0] == projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskId) {
                html += "<td>" + projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskCount/2 + "</td>";
                //for testing un comment it
                //html += "<td>" + projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskName + '_' + projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskId + "</td>";

                var l;

                 for(l = 0; l < specificTaskTotalDaysSpent.length; l++) {
                     if (projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskId == specificTaskTotalDaysSpent[l].taskId) {
                         specificTaskTotalDaysSpent[l].days = specificTaskTotalDaysSpent[l].days + (projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskCount / 2);
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                if(specificTaskTotalDaysSpent.length == 0 || (l == specificTaskTotalDaysSpent.length)){//||
              TotalTimeSpentOnTaskAdd(projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskId, tableHeaderData[k].split('_')[1], projectAndTask[i].taskArray[j].taskCount / 2);
                }

               loopLastIndex = ++k; //save the last position of array i.e., again start for next index
               break;
           }
           else {
               html += "<td>  </td>";
           }
       }
   }
   html += "</tr>";
}

html +="</tr>";
html +="</table>";
$jq("#ProjectsPreviousDaysInfo").html(" ");
$jq("#ProjectsPreviousDaysInfo").html(html);
```

Comment: Could we see the html output you're getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3189208/2333214

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan This is a screen grab of the table, not the html.

Comment: @Aaron code also added

Comment: The code you added is the JavaScript that generates the HTML, what we've asked for is the rendered *HTML*, right-click the `<table>` element -> inspect element -> 'copy (the `<table>`) as HTML' -> paste into question.

Comment: @DavidThomas question have solve even without any details! cheers for intelligent pawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two lines should do the needful (considering your class name is `headerclassname`)

```
$('td.headerclassname').hide(); // hide the column header th

$('tr').each(function(){
     $(this).find('td:eq('+$('td.headerclassname').index()+')').hide();
});
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvysb76a/)**

Comment: header is hide but column doesn't

Comment: although i have solved the problem by adding same class to every row and now i tried your updated solution it worked perfectly. thanks and you should need to share this code earlier . anyhow thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a logic that uses indexes to hide columns. 
Like this ;

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
                <td class="c1">Test</td>
                <td class="c2">Test2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>Val</td>
                <td>Val1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Val</td>
                <td>Val1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
        hideColumn("c1");
      })

 function hideColumn(className){

        var columnIndex = $("#table thead tr td."+className).index();

        $("#table thead tr td:eq("+columnIndex+")").hide();

        $("#table tbody tr").each(function(){
            $(this).find("td:eq("+columnIndex+")").hide();
        });
 }

</script>
```